# A strange way to prove uniqueness

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Prove there is a unique linear map $f:U\bigoplus V\rightarrow U+V$

Proof:

The only choice is $f(u,v)=u+v$ because if $f$ were linear, $f(u,v)=f((u,0)+(0,v))=f(u,0)+f(0,v)$. An then show this is actually linear.

Q.E.D.

But I don't get why the first line shows uniqueness? Why can't there be another $g(u,v)=g(u,0)+g(0,v)$

Comment: It's clearly not true. E.g. consider $2f$.

Comment: You need to ask for more before you get uniqueness. There is a unique linear map which restricts to the identity on $U$ and on $V$, for example. (I assume that $U + V$ here is a not-necessarily-direct sum.)